# Передать значение из dropdown в контроллер

Tags: php, yii2

Есть выпадающий список во вью

```
    <?php
    $items = [201=>'Тест',202=>'Тест2'];
    echo Html::dropDownList('list', 'null', $items);
    ?>
```

Хочу передать выбранное значение в контроллер, чтобы выбранное значение стало входным параметром для функции.

```
if(isset($_GET['send_orders']))
        {

            $lk_number = $_POST['list'];

            $get_lk = Salesorder::getTestLkData($lk_number);
}
```

Что делаю не так?

Весь код формы(кроме пространств имен)

```
<div class="vtiger-salesorder-index">
<?php
$items = [201=>'Тест',202=>'Тест2'];
echo Html::dropDownList('list', 'null', $items);
?>
<h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

<?= Html::a( ' Отправка заказов', ['order/index', 'send_orders' => 6],['class' => 'btn btn-success btn-md glyphicon glyphicon-send']);?>
```

Comment: а почему у вас, что то по GET и что то по POST? вы одновременно и get и post делаете ?

Comment: @Arsen `$_GET` в данном случае обрабатывает нажатие соответствующей кнопки. `<?= Html::a( ' Отправка заказов', ['order/index', 'send_orders' => 6],['class' => 'btn btn-success btn-md glyphicon glyphicon-send']);?>`

Comment: а вы можете показать весь код формы, через который делаете отправку ?

Comment: @Arsen дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня такое ощущение что вы не корректно собрали форму для отправки данных, приведу пример, ваша форма для отправки данных должна выглядеть примерно так:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin();

$items = [201=>'Тест',202=>'Тест2'];
echo Html::dropDownList('list', 'null', $items);
 ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```